# lightweight draggable jQuery, drag the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

Online sample: http://jsfiddle.net/5tpPx/
The issue is that, if drag the black square and the mouse off the red square area, the black square follows mouse's movement once move the mouse back to the red square area. How to fix that?  like once the mouse of side of the red square area then trigger `mouseup`?

```
  // jQuery draggable plugin
(function($) {
    $.fn.draggable = function(options) {
        var $handle = this,
            $draggable = this,
            draggable = $draggable[0];
            parent = draggable.parentNode;

        options = $.extend({}, {
            handle: null,
            cursor: 'move'
        }, options);

        if( options.handle ) {
            $handle = $(options.handle);
        }

        $handle
            .css('cursor', options.cursor)
            .on("mousedown", function(e) {
                var p_dims = parent.getBoundingClientRect(),
                    d_dims = draggable.getBoundingClientRect(),
                    w = p_dims.width-d_dims.width,
                    h = p_dims.height-d_dims.height;

                var x = d_dims.left - e.pageX,
                    y = d_dims.top - e.pageY,
                    z = $draggable.css('z-index');

                $draggable.css('z-index', 100000);

                $(document.documentElement)
                    .on('mousemove.draggable', function(e) {
                        var l = x+e.pageX-p_dims.left,
                            t = y+e.pageY-p_dims.top;
                        if (l < 0) l = 0;
                        else if (l > w) l = w;
                        if (t < 0) t = 0;
                        else if (t > h) t = h;
                        console.log(l, t);
                        $draggable.offset({
                            left: l+p_dims.left,
                            top: t+p_dims.top
                        });
                    })
                    .one('mouseup', function() {
                        $(this).off('mousemove.draggable');
                        $draggable.css('z-index', z);
                    });

                // disable selection
                e.preventDefault();
            });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.drag').draggable();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your code http://jsfiddle.net/5tpPx/3/

added a class **dragoff** when leaving the parent container and removing it only when the mousedown event it fired again.

Also checked if handle has class dragoff before setting its coords.

```
// jQuery draggable plugin
(function($) {
    $.fn.draggable = function(options) {
        var $handle = this,
            $draggable = this,
            draggable = $draggable[0];
            parent = draggable.parentNode;

        options = $.extend({}, {
            handle: null,
            cursor: 'move'
        }, options);

        if( options.handle ) {
            $handle = $(options.handle);
        }


        $handle
            .css('cursor', options.cursor)
            .on("mousedown", function(e) {
                $handle.removeClass('dragoff')
                var p_dims = parent.getBoundingClientRect(),
                    d_dims = draggable.getBoundingClientRect(),
                    w = p_dims.width-d_dims.width,
                    h = p_dims.height-d_dims.height;

                var x = d_dims.left - e.pageX,
                    y = d_dims.top - e.pageY,
                    z = $draggable.css('z-index');

                $draggable.css('z-index', 100000);

                $(document.documentElement)
                    .on('mousemove.draggable', function(e) {
                        if($handle.hasClass('dragoff')){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                        var l = x+e.pageX-p_dims.left,
                            t = y+e.pageY-p_dims.top;
                        if (l < 0) l = 0;
                        else if (l > w) l = w;
                        if (t < 0) t = 0;
                        else if (t > h) t = h;
                        console.log(l, t);
                        $draggable.offset({
                            left: l+p_dims.left,
                            top: t+p_dims.top
                        });
                    })
                    .one('mouseup', function() {
                        $(this).off('mousemove.draggable');
                        $draggable.css('z-index', z);
                    });

                // disable selection
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        $handle.parent().hover(function(){

        },function(){
            $handle.addClass('dragoff')
        })
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.drag').draggable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there's a typo in this script. It says:

```
.one('mouseup', function() {
                        $(this).off('mousemove.draggable');
                        $draggable.css('z-index', z);
                    });
```

But should be:

```
.on('mouseup', function() {
                        $(this).off('mousemove.draggable');
                        $draggable.css('z-index', z);
                    });
```